# How do I fix my gnome display manager in recovery mode?

Tags: linux, gnome, kali-linux

I am using kali Linux 1.0.9 and when I boot it doesn't show the login screen just a command line for login. Before the login it shows `Not starting Gnome display manager-it is not set as default`. I have not used any other display manager  so I don't know what is wrong. Can I restart it in any way?

Other Details. When I go to recovery mode and type gnome-display in the terminal it shows me this error. Window display manager error. I have not installed any new video cards or hardware or software. Everything is just as I had left it when I installed it yesterday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to the directory `/etc/X11` and took created a file default-display-manager (for some reason it was missing). Then typed `/usr/bin/gdm3`. After rebooting it was fine but then it started showing a black screen when I log in so I installed another display manager(KDE).